# How to use predicate to obtain unique objects from NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

How to use predicate to obtain unique objects from `NSArray`? In the case below, the result should be `typeA` and `typeD`.

Interface of class `MyType`:

```
@interface MyType : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *identifier;

@end
```

Interface of class `MyTask`:

```
@interface MyTask : NSObject 

@property MyType *type

@end
```

Example code:

```
// type objects
MyType *typeA = [[MyType alloc] init];
[typeA setName:@“A”];
[typeA setIdentifier:@“A”];

MyType *typeB = [[MyType alloc] init];
[typeB setName:@“B”];
[typeB setIdentifier:@“B”];

MyType *typeC = [[MyType alloc] init];
[typeC setName:@“C”];
[typeC setIdentifier:@“C”];

MyType *typeD = [[MyType alloc] init];
[typeD setName:@“D”];
[typeD setIdentifier:@“D”];

// task objects
MyTask *task1 = [[MyTask alloc] init];
[task1 setType:typeA];

MyTask *task2 = [MyTask alloc] init];
[task2 setType:typeA];

MyTask *task3 = [[MyTask alloc] init];
[task3 setType:typeD];

MyTask *task4 = [[MyTask alloc] init];
[task4 setType:typeA];

NSArray *tasks = @[task1, task2, task3, task4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**Key-Value Coding** collection operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)  `@distinctUnionOfObjects`. In your case,

```
[tasks valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.type"]
```

returns an array with the elements `typeA` and `typeD` (not necessarily in that order),
and

```
[tasks valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.type.name"]
```

returns an array with the strings `"A"` and `"D"`.

Comment: Does this require OP to implement hash or compareMyType: in MyType before it works?

Comment: @WarrenBurton: It depends. The default implementation of isEqual (inherited from NSObject) compares the pointers. You have to override it only if that is not sufficient (e.g. if two different MyType object should be considered equal if they have the same identifier).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.type==%@", typeD];
NSArray* array = [tasks filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The `array` object should contain one object: `task3`. This also assumes you have the `type` getter too, not just the setter (`setType`).